# im trying to generate models from an existing sql database on aspnet Core using Scaffold-DbContext but i keep getting Script Halted Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, scaffolding

im trying to generate models from an existing sql database on aspnet **Core** using **Scaffold-DbContext** but i keep getting **Script Halted Error**

Scaffolding code used : Scaffold-DbContext "Server=SHAREDDBSQL\MSSQLSERVER2K8;Initial Catalog=AspnetCore-AngularTest;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=userappro;Password=userappro;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
   [ERROR RECEIVED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbbij.png)

Comment: Which EF Core version are you using? Have you tried the command-line tool instead, ie `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold` ?

Comment: BTW SQL Server 2008 is no longer supported - it's not even in extended support where you pay per incident for a custom fix. The connection string specifies encryption but `TrustServerCertificate=**False**`. This means the client will reject connections if the server uses a self-signed certificate. Is the server configured for TLS1.0 at least? Can you connect to that server with SSL in the first place? Almost everyone expects TLS1.2 these days

Comment: SQL Server 2008 (even R2) and Windows Server 2008 (and R2) [had to be patched to support TLS1.2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server) Nowadays, SSLv3 and even TLS1.0 are *disabled by default* in OSs and libraries. All supported Windows and SQL Server versions use TLS1.2 by default, with fallback to 1.1.

Comment: im using 3.1.1 (latest version) , i tried Command line tool instead and it tell that the scaffold command is not recognized

Comment: Have you installed the [EF tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet) in the first place? Again, can you connect to that server with SSMS or sqlcmd? That connection string won't work unless you use a certificate issued by an external provider like LetsEncrypt. Or, you are in a Windows Domain with Certificate Services configured and working. You wouldn't be using a username/password in that case though

Comment: yes EF Tools is already installed , im using SSMS ? should i install sql server 2012 ?

Comment: If ef tools are installed you shouldn't be getting errors about the scaffold command. SQL Server 2012 and 2014 are out of mainstream support too, but simply installing them won't fix TLS issues. The database you use should be as close as possible to the production databases anyway.  *Can* you connect to the database when using encryption?

Comment: yes i connect to the database

Comment: Which OS are you using too? If you use one with an outdated Powershell version, the script may fail simply because it doesn't target that version. For *un*supported OS versions, it doesn't have to. [In this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58607253/when-executing-the-command-scaffold-dbcontext-i-get-the-error-scripthalted) the problem was a Win 7.0 machine with Powershell 2.0 instead of 5.1

Comment: yeah i guess that's the issue im using win 7.0 , powershell version is 1.0

Comment: thank you sir for your time , i really appreciate it